# Linear algebra book for previous graduate student

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I graduated maths in ~2014 and since then have been more doing software. I would like to "restudy" linear algebra and I am looking for a book recommendation for my profile, i.e. that book should not be addressed to someone who never did maths :)

Best

Comment: I'd say Linear Algebra Done Right is a popular choice for undergrads. Although, just to throw something interesting in the mix, you may want to check out "Finite-Dimensional Linear Analysis: A Systematic Presentation in Problem Form" by Ju. I. Ljubic. It's a problem solving book that builds from the very basics all the way up to concepts in functional analysis. The only downside is the text is old, so the formatting and terminology is a bit dated, but it's definitely worth going through.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but as I say in the post, I need something that is not necessarily addressed for undergrad

Comment: I quite enjoy a set of notes called “linear algebra done wrong”.

Comment: Maybe try *Advanced Linear Algebra* by Loehr or Roman.